# Is there any method to create trigger and trigger function in a single query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, ddl, database-trigger

I have a problem with PostgreSQL. I want to create a trigger and trigger function in a single query, so I can make trigger in a faster way.
this is my trigger function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION public.tda_a1()
      RETURNS trigger
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
      COST 100.0
      VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
      COST 100.0
    AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM ref_dati2 where kd_propinsi = OLD.kd_propinsi;
      RETURN OLD;
    END;
    $BODY$;
```

And this is the trigger :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER tda_a1
      BEFORE DELETE
      ON public.ref_propinsi
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.tda_a1();
```

I have tried to join those into a single query but failed. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Why do you think that would be "faster"? How long does it currently take to run those two statements? How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it doesnt take long time if there are only 2 or 3 triggers, but I have 192 triggers. I want to execute them in single query like I have done in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course I can execute them 1 by 1, but it will take long time and I have to be carefull for each execution. Actually I can execute multiple triggers(that bind to specific action on table) in a single query, but doesnt work to the trigger function

Comment: I still don't understand what the actual problem is you are trying to solve. There is no way to define a trigger in Postgres without a function. The function can be re-used indeed, so you don't need two statements for every trigger. You say you "need to be careful for each execution". This sounds to me if you are missing a proper concept on how to manage your schema definition and migration. Look into tools like [Liquibase](liquibase.org) or Flyway which will help you in managing and running your schema migrations

Answer (score 1):

**update** Confused by:

> I have 192 triggers. I want to execute them in single query like I have done in Oracle

The below is answer for misunderstood original post. It answers the performance of wrapping creation of several triggers in one go. While what OP probably meant was defining PGSQL in trigger itself, not as a separate trigger function.

prepare:

```
t=# create schema s1;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# set search_path to s1;
SET
t=# create table t1 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# \timing on
Timing is on.
```

run in one `DO` statement:

```
t=# do
$$
begin
for i in 1..99 loop
execute format('create function %I() returns trigger as $f$begin return new;end;$f$ language plpgsql','f'||i);
execute format('create trigger %I before delete on t1 for each row execute procedure %I()','t'||i,'f'||i);
end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
Time: 54.545 ms
```

Time took: `Time: 54.545 ms`

Now using same `DO` to generate script of separated statements:

```
t=# do
$$
begin
for i in 1..99 loop
raise info '%', format('create function %I() returns trigger as $f$begin return new;end;$f$ language plpgsql;','f'||i);
raise info '%', format('create trigger %I before delete on t1 for each row execute procedure %I();','t'||i,'f'||i);
end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

saving it to a file:

```
t=# \! vi s1
:%s/INFO:  //g
-- adding select clock_timestamp(); and begin; end; to avoid overhead on autocommit each statement
t=# \! wc -l s1
202 s1
```

202 lines. 198 statements plus 4 added. sweeping up and running:

```
t=# drop schema s1 cascade;
DROP SCHEMA
t=# create schema s1;
CREATE SCHEMA
t=# set search_path to s1;
SET
t=# create table t1 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# \i s1
        clock_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2017-06-22 07:49:05.78448+00
(1 row)

Time: 0.202 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 1.407 ms
CREATE TRIGGER
....
....
CREATE TRIGGER
Time: 1.033 ms
        clock_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2017-06-22 07:49:05.823402+00
(1 row)
```

time diff:

```
t=# select '2017-06-22 07:49:05.823402+00'::timestamptz - '2017-06-22 07:49:05.78448+00'::timestamptz;
    ?column?
-----------------
 00:00:00.038922
(1 row)
```

Time `38.922` ms

I did the test several times and dynamic execution is sometimes faster, sometimes not. The main performance boost you can achieve is by running multiline script in one transaction. But again - we are comparing milliseconds here...

Also - maybe you meant something ELSE by one statement?.. If so please update the original post with code examples of how you did it in Oracle

Comment: In Oracle it's a **single** `create trigger` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just realyzed that single statement meant defining pgsql block inside trigger definition! not several triggers in one statement. G! :) > "I have 192 triggers. I want to execute them in single query like I have done in Oracle" totally confused me. I even reread the CREATE TRIGGER reference, looking for magic. All the time thinking "why would you want one statement for several trigegrs in first place!"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your answers but finally I have found the answer,
I just removed this script from my query.

```
  NOT LEAKPROOF 
  COST 100.0
```

that is the default from pgadmin, when I removed it I can run trigger an trigger function in a single query as many as I want

Comment: you still can't create a trigger **and** a trigger function in the same statement.